# Angular 6 - Google sign in - token refresh with SocialLoginModule

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt, google-authentication, social-authentication

So I'm building a web application using Angular 6 and I implemented google sign in with SocialLogin library.
This is my code:

```
public socialSignIn(socialPlatform : string) {
      let socialPlatformProvider;
      if(socialPlatform == "facebook"){
        socialPlatformProvider = FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID;
      }else if(socialPlatform == "google"){
        socialPlatformProvider = GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID;
      }

      this.socialAuthService.signIn(socialPlatformProvider).then(
        (userData) => {

        let user: User = new User();
        let newuserrequest: NewUserRequest = new NewUserRequest();

        user.email = userData.email;
        var username;
        username = userData.name;
        var uuid = this.newGuid();
        newuserrequest.requestId = uuid;
        newuserrequest.user = user;
        newuserrequest.accountId = userData.id;
        newuserrequest.accountIdToken = userData.idToken;
        this.newuserrequest = Array<NewUserRequest>(newuserrequest);
        this.personname2 = userData.name;
        this.personname = this.personname2.toString();
        console.log('Personname: ' + this.personname);
        this.div = document.getElementById("name");
        this.div.textContent = this.personname;
        var token;
        token = userData.idToken;
        this.saveValueUser(username, user.email);

        this.islogedin = true;

        this.saveValue(token);
        this.communicator = new CommunicatorService(this.httpClient);
        var url;
        url = "myurl/newuser";
        this.communicator.getDataFromServer(this.newuserrequest, url)
        .subscribe(
          (data:any) => {
            console.log(data);
          }
        );
        }
      );
    }
```

This code works fine, but only for 1 hour. Using JWT-helper-service I created a method that lets me know if my token is still valid and also how long is it valid. This is the method:

```
  private tokenHandler(){
    this.helper = new JwtHelperService();
    this.isExpired = this.helper.isTokenExpired(this.token);
    if(this.isExpired != true) {
      this.expirationDate = this.helper.getTokenExpirationDate(this.token);
    }
    console.log("Is expired: " + this.isExpired);
    console.log("Expiration date: " + this.expirationDate);
    if(this.isExpired == true){
      this.signOut();
    }
  }
```

How can I refresh token before it gets expired?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a schedule call in your code after the first acquisition of the token that sets up a countdown timer and trigger the renewal at a specific time before expiration.

Look at this link https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/05-token-renewal for an example

That is specific to AuthO libraries but you could easily adapt it to your token retrieval library.

Also that example is geared toward angular 2 so remember that rxjs made a few changes (e.g. instead of observable.of() now we use just of() etc.)

Let me know if you need more help.